# Unable to create multiple brokers on local machine: common.InconsistentBrokerIdException

Tags: apache-kafka

**Steps:**

1. Started Zookeeper instance: `bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh
   config/zookeeper.properties` :**SUCCESS**
2. Started Broker 0 :
   `bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server-0.properties` **SUCCESS**
3. Started Broker 1 :
   `bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server-1.properties` **FAILED**

> ERROR: a.common.InconsistentBrokerIdException: Configured broker.id 1
>   doesn't match stored broker.id 0 in meta.properties. If you moved your
>   data, make sure your configured broker.id matches. If you intend to
>   create a new broker, you should remove all data in your

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Running multiple brokers on one machine doesn't increase performance or stability

Comment: @cricket_007 No, I am just learning. It's my first day looking into Kafka.

Answer (score 1):

Edit config/server-1.properties and replace the existing config values as follows:

```
broker.id=1
port=9093
log.dir=/tmp/kafka-logs-1
```

Also make sure that there are no multiple references of log.dir in the property file which might overwrite the previous value.

Comment: ` ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.common.InconsistentBrokerIdException: Configured broker.id 2 doesn't match stored broker.id 1 in meta.properties. If you moved your data, make sure your configured broker.id matches. If you intend to create a new broker, you should remove all data in your data directories (log.dirs).
 at kafka.server.KafkaServer.getBrokerIdAndOfflineDirs(KafkaServer.scala:686)
 at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:209)
 at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(Kaf...`

Comment: @Samur Delete the log directories and restart the processes

Comment: @cricket_007 I have already deleted whatever was inside log directory. Or are you referring to something else? Btw I am also not able to find meta.properties file

Comment: @SamuraiJack `dataDir` from Zookeeper and `log.dirs` from Kafka properties should be cleaned if trying to start fresh

Comment: @cricket_007 I dont see log.dirs directory anywhere. https://imgur.com/a/P4gunMh

Comment: `grep log config/server.properties` @Samur

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208437/discussion-between-samuraijack-and-cricket-007).

Comment: @cricket_007 can you please come to chat for a minute? Plz

Comment: @SamuraiJack I don't know what folder you are looking at... `grep log ~/kafka_2.12-2.4.0/config/server*.properties`

Comment: @cricket_007 I am not looking for server.properties. I know where they are. I am looking for log.dir and dataDir that you have mentioned.

Comment: If you have already deleted the log dir. Clear the state from the zookeeper as well.
run zkCli.sh file in zookeeper bin directory and clear the topics and broker ids

`rmr /brokers/topics`
 and `rmr /broker/ids`